# Message keeps failing to send with Sinch

Tags: android, instant-messaging, sinch

I've been following this tutorial at https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/#message and I'm having trouble sending the message to another user. When I write a message and send it. I keep getting a toast message that says "Message Failed To Send".

This is my MessageService Activity:

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "xxxx";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "yyyy";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
    private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
    private MessageClient messageClient = null;
    private String currentUserId;
    private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.jordanpeterson.textly.messages.ListUsersActivity");
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadCaster;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // get the current user id from parse
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        }

        broadCaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void startSinchClient(String userame) {
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this)
                .userId(userame).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT)
                .build();
        // this client listener requires that you define
        // a few methods below

        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        // Messaging is "turned-on", but calling is not
        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

        sinchClient.checkManifest();
        sinchClient.start();

    }

    private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
    }

    // The next 5 methods are for the sinch client listener

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
        broadCaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        sinchClient = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
        broadCaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        sinchClient = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
            ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        // No code in here yet

    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
        // No code in here yet either

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceInterface;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId,
                    textBody);
            messageClient.send(message);
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
        sinchClient.terminate();
    }

    // Public interface for ListUsersActivity & MessagingActivity
    public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my MessagingActivity:

```
private String mRecipientId;
    private EditText mMessageBodyField;
    private String mMessageBody;
    private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
    private String mCurrentUserId;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
    private MessageClientListener messageClientListener = new MyMessageClientListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messaging_sinch);

        bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection,
                BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // Get RecipientId from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mRecipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
        mCurrentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

        mMessageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);

        // Listen for a click on the send button
        findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Send The Message!
                        mMessageBody = mMessageBodyField.getText().toString();
                        if (mMessageBody.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this,
                                    "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            return;
                        }
                        messageService.sendMessage(mRecipientId, mMessageBody);
                        mMessageBodyField.setText("");

                    }
                });
    }

    // Unbind the service when the activity is destroyed
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        messageService.removeMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName,
                IBinder iBinder) {
            messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
            messageService.addMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            messageService = null;

        }

    }

    private class MyMessageClientListener implements MessageClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
            Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this, "Message failed to send.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
            // Display an incoming message

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message,
                String recipientId) {
            // Display the message that was just sent

            // Later, I'll show you how to store the
            // Message in Parse, so you can retrieve and
            // display them every time the conversation is opened

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client,
                MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {

        }

        // Don't worry about this right now
        @Override
        public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message,
                List<PushPair> pushPairs) {

        }

    }

}
```

And this is my ListUsersActivity:

```
public class ListUsersActivity extends Activity {

    private String mCurrentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNamesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mNames;
    private ListView mUsersListView;
    private Button mLogoutButton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);

        mCurrentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        mNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        // Don't include yourself!
        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", mCurrentUserId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                        mNames.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    }
                    mUsersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    mNamesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            mNames);
                    mUsersListView.setAdapter(mNamesArrayAdapter);
                    mUsersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(mNames, i);

                                }

                                private void openConversation(
                                        ArrayList<String> mNames, int pos) {
                                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser
                                            .getQuery();
                                    query.whereEqualTo("username",
                                            mNames.get(pos));
                                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void done(List<ParseUser> user,
                                                ParseException e) {
                                            if (e == null) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListUsersActivity.this, MessagingActivity.class);
                                                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(
                                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "Error finding that user!",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .show();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ListUsersActivity.this,
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        });



        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        // broadcast receiver to listen for the broadcast
        // from MessageService

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
                Toast.makeText(ListUsersActivity.this, "Sinch has started and is working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                // Show a toast message is the Sinch service failed to start
                if (!success) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListUsersActivity.this,
                            "Messaging service failed to start",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        };

        LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(this)
                .registerReceiver(
                        mReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(
                                "com.jordanpeterson.textly.messages.ListUsersActivity"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print the message error because you may have it for many reasons.
Under onMessageFailed function, add this to see the failure message:

```
Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this,failureInfo.getSinchError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: When I send the message the toast message says "UserNotFound". I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: The message "user not found" means that no SinchClient was started with the recipient Id. So you have to log in with the user to which you want to send the message at least once!

Comment: It's working now! I didn't realize it was that easy.

Comment: @MahaBenabbou That was my problem as well, even though I'm using iOS! Thank you so much